# How to delete already Select table?

Tags: mysql

I have selected  Duplicate table using Following Query

```
SELECT
    y.Entity,y.ExpenseTypeCode,y.ExpenseType,y.LOB,y.Center,y.Location,y.Amount,y.APSupplierID,y.ExpenseReportID,y.Employee,y.ReportDate,y.ExpenseDate,y.Description
    FROM dbo.TotalsByGLCenter$ y
        INNER JOIN (SELECT
                        Entity,ExpenseTypeCode,ExpenseType,LOB,Center,Location,Amount,Description,APSupplierID,ExpenseReportID,Employee,ReportDate,ExpenseDate, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
                        FROM  dbo.TotalsByGLCenter$
                        GROUP BY Entity,ExpenseTypeCode,ExpenseType,LOB,Center,Location,Amount,APSupplierID,ExpenseReportID,Employee,ReportDate,ExpenseDate,Description
                        HAVING COUNT(*)>1
                    ) dt ON y.Entity=dt.Entity and y.ExpenseTypeCode=dt.ExpenseTypeCode and y.ExpenseType=dt.ExpenseType and y.LOB=dt.LOB and y.Location=dt.Location and y.Center=dt.Center  and y.Amount=dt.Amount and y.APSupplierID=dt.APSupplierID and y.ExpenseReportID=dt.ExpenseReportID and y.Employee=dt.Employee and y.ReportDate=dt.ReportDate and y.ExpenseDate=dt.ExpenseDate and  y.Description=dt.Description
```

i Want Delete selected Query  . how can I use delete Query Above Query Statement ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this mate ,

```
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE id IN ( 
Select (
your select query
) As alias 
)
```